# Get URL of page without domain using the same site structure

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have the following problem: I have a set of domains with the same url structure:

```
domain-a.com/london/
domain-b/london/
domain-c/london/
```

I want to do the following thing:
If you are on `domain-a.com/london/`, I want "related" links underneath pointing to `domain-b.com/london/` and `domain-c.com/london/`

I want these links to appear automatically using the URL of the current page, remove the domain so that only the rest is left - in my example: `/london/` and add the other domains in front of this.
I know I have to use `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` to get the rest of the URL but I don't know how to create a link using this function.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

function generateLink($url, $uri){    
    if(strpos($url,'domain-a.com') !== false){
        $link = 'http://domain-b.com' . $uri;
        return $link;
    }else if(strpos($url,'domain-b.com') !== false){
        $link = 'http://domain-c.com' . $uri;
        return $link;
    }else if(strpos($url,'domain-c.com') !== false){
        $link = 'http://domain-a.com' . $uri;
        return $link;
    }
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo generateLink($url, $uri); ?>">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the link will be displayed like this: 

`http://www.domain-a.com/<?php echo generateLink($url, $uri); ?>`

Comment: Ensure your php file is a php file and that the php codeblock is within php tags.  I've edited my answer to add them in there.